# Newbie to mac os, how to checkin into local git, push to remote, and to heroku in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, git, unix

I am a .net guy who is playing with node and ruby on rails, also I am new to mac os and scripting. I am experimenting with code and every now and then whenever I write code I have to do some steps over and over again, mainly checking them in locally to my git, then push to github, and the push to heroku.

Now is there a way to save or create a shortcut script that will do things in a sequence, assuming sequential success in every step before moving to the other?

Something along the line of automating these commands :

```
    git add .
    git commit -m "added mayo to the fries"
    git push
    git push heroku master
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a little bit more flavor to handle a few options like newrelic, maintenance mode, and migrations in your 'commit_and_deploy.sh' script. 'ACCTID', 'APPID' below are specific to your NewRelic account if you add it.

```
git add .
git commit -m "added mayo to the fries"
git push
#disbles ping targets if you set up in newrelic
curl https://heroku.newrelic.com/accounts/ACCTID/applications/APPID/ping_targets/disable -X      POST -H "X-Api-Key: APIKEY"
#turn on maintenance mode
heroku maintenance:on --app myApp
#push to heroku
git push --force heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate --app myApp
#enables back on
curl https://heroku.newrelic.com/accounts/ACCTID/applications/APPID/ping_targets/enable -X POST -H "X-Api-Key: APIKEY"
heroku maintenance:off --app myApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Add that to a shell script and run the script - similar to a 'batch' file in windows/DOS.  Naturally, you'll want to replace that commit message with an variable argument, and pass that in when calling the script.

Answer (score 0):

So you might want to create a script that look like

---

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

myAppName="MySuperAppDev"

if [[ -z $1 ]] ;then
   echo "No commitment message supplied"
   exit 1
fi

if git add . && \
git commit -m "$1" &&\
git push ; then
    #disbles ping targets if you set up in newrelic
    curl https://heroku.newrelic.com/accounts/ACCTID/applications/APPID/ping_targets/disable -X      POST -H "X-Api-Key: APIKEY"
    #turn on maintenance mode
    heroku maintenance:on --app $myAppName
    #push to heroku
    git push --force heroku master
    heroku run rake db:migrate --app $myAppName
    #enables back on
    curl https://heroku.newrelic.com/accounts/ACCTID/applications/APPID/ping_targets/enable -X POST -H "X-Api-Key: APIKEY"
    heroku maintenance:off --app $myAppName
fi
```

---

Remember to run `chmod +x myscript` after you save it so that it can execute

This is still a bit crude, but it should

1. start a little faster (the #! line)
2. Be easier to use for different apps by editing the 3rd line
3. Do simple error checking
   on the git commit

NB I have not tested this at all!